# Parsing / Converting a string array to integers with use of filter and map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was thinking about a problem the other day. Say I have an array like so

```
var stringArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
```

and I want to create a similar array where I convert the array items in stringArray to numbers/integers. I can map to a new array parsing each item using parseInt or by using + (I really like doing that).

```
var numberArray = stringArray.map((n) => +n);
```

Now I would like to filter this so I only return items that are larger than 5, like so...

```
var numberArray = stringArray.map((n) => +n).filter((n) => n > 5);
```

this is great but I wonder, do I need to chain the .map and the .filter or could I use a single method like so...

```
var numberArray = stringArray.filter((n) => {
  if (+n > 5) {
    return +n;
  }
});
```

this doesn't give the desired result, what is returned is `["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]` can anyone see where I am going wrong or why the parse isn't working.

Comment: If you want to use single method then you can use parsetInt() method.

Comment: `array#filter` returns the subset of the array for which the condition is evaluated as `true`. Maybe this you can try `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"].map(Number).filter(n => n > 5)`

Comment: `map` returns a new array with the elements being processed by the specified function, hence your strings are ints in the new array. However, `filter`, while also returning a new array, unlike `map`, only returns elements that the specified function returns true for but you can't change the actual value before it is returned.

Comment: `do I need to chain the .map and the .filter` - technically, you don't, but it's much better this way.

Answer (score 2):

With a single loop, you need to filter and convert the value in one step. You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and concat the result array only if the value is greater than the wanted value. If not return the temporary array.

```js
var stringArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    numberArray = stringArray.reduce((r, n) => +n > 5 ? r.concat(+n) : r, []);

console.log(numberArray);
```

Comment: Hi can you explain why the concatenated string gets converted to an array? nice approach btw....

Comment: it is an array which is concatinated with a number, because of the `initalValue` for the accumulator.

Comment: Now that you are using `reduce` and `concat` I assume that if the initial desire for OP was to see if it can be done with just 1 method instead of 2 i.e: `map` and `filter` that it it still is the same difference.

Comment: map converts to a number, for each element and filter filters, but do not convert the elements. you need two loops to get the result. `reduce` is is just the swiss knife of array functions, because you could change the result and make some test before.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your last approach is that filter method, method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function,
it will only include the elements that return true, so undefined will coerce to false, and any number >0 will coerce to true.

I will suggest the example provided by @HassanImam

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"].map(Number).filter(n => n > 5);
```

```js
console.log(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"].map(Number).filter(n => n > 5));
```